# typeof variable !== 'undefined' converts a variable to a string?

Tags: javascript

If `typeof` operator returns a *string*, and the variable `third` becomes a *string*. How does javascript change `third` back to a *number* as it enters the for loop?

```
function range(start, end, third){
  var numberlist = [];
 if(typeof third !== 'undefined'){ 
    if (start < end){
      for (var count = start; count < end; count++){
    numberlist.push(count + third);
    }
  } 
 }
}
console.log(range(1,10,2));
```

Comment: Where are you calling `range` function?

Comment: "the variable third becomes a string" - How?

Comment: typeof third. I thought typeof converts the variable to a string?

Comment: `typeof third` *returns* a string.

Comment: typeof will not convert the variable it will give the type of variable which is number type in your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`third` does not become a string here.

`typeof third !== 'undefined'` could be rewritten as `(typeof third) !== 'undefined'`, or even more verbose:

```
let m = typeof(third)
if(m !== 'undefined') { }
```

In either case, it is returning a string, not assigning that string to the variable `third`.

You should also `return numberlist` at the end of your function if you want `console.log(range(1,10,2))` to be meaningful.

Answer (score 0):

Range here is just filling an array, but it's never returned, thus `console.log` is reporting `"undefined"`. Add the following at the end of the function: `return numberlist;`

Answer (score 0):

I would try this:

see it here: https://jsfiddle.net/wpfcv401/2/

```
function range(start, end, third) {
  var numberlist = [];

  if(third) {            //if third is NOT null and not undefined
     if(isNaN(third)) {  //if third is not a number
        third = parseInt(third);
     }
     if(!isNaN(third)){
        if (start < end){
           for (var count = start; count < end; count++){
              numberlist.push((count + third));
              alert('pushing ' + (count + third));
           }
        }
      }
   }
}
console.log(range(1,3,2));
```